# Каким образом в Вордпресс сделать возможность добавлять фото в форме комментирования и выводить как аватарки?

Tags: wordpress

Делаю на странице вывод своего шаблона комментирования.
Вывод комментариев сделал, форму комментирования со своими полями сделал.

Как сделать вывод полей в шаблоне комментариев и сделать возможным загрузку фото и рамещение их как аватарок?

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Страница "Отзывы"
Template Post Type: page
*/
$fields = (object)get_fields(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <section>
        <div class="title_wrap text_center">
            <div class="shadow_title "><?= $fields->title ?></div>
            <h1 class="title "><?= $fields->title ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="all_testimonials">
            <?php if($fields->testimonials): ?>
                <?php foreach($fields->testimonials AS $t): ?>
            <div class="one_wrap">
                <div class="single_testimonial clearfix">
                    <div class="foto">
                        <img src="<?= WP_img_resize($t['photo'], 127, 127, true) ?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial_content">
                        <div class="fst clearfix">
                            <div class="name"><?= $t['name'] ?></div>
                            <div class="date"><?= $t['date_comment'] ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <?php if($t['order']): ?>
                        <div class="zakaz"><?= $t['order'] ?></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="text">
                            <?= $t['comment'] ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="asnwer box-shadow">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="title">
                            Ответ представителя:
                        </div>
                        <div class="date">
                            <?= $t['date_answer'] ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= $t['answer'] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $comments = get_comments() ? get_comments() : ''; if($comments): ?>
                <?php foreach($comments AS $comment): ?>
                    <?php if($comment->comment_parent == 0): ?>
            <div class="one_wrap">
                <div class="single_testimonial clearfix">
                    <div class="foto">
                        <img src="<?= WP_img_resize($t['photo'], 127, 127, true) ?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial_content">
                        <div class="fst clearfix">
                            <div class="name"><?= $comment->comment_author ?></div>
                            <div class="date"><?= dateFormat($comment->comment_date) ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <?= $comment->comment_content ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <?php foreach($comments AS $_c): ?>
                            <?php if($_c->comment_parent == $comment->comment_ID): ?>
                                <div class="asnwer box-shadow">
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                        <div class="title">
                                            Ответ представителя:
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="date">
                                            <?= dateFormat($_c->comment_date) ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?= $_c->comment_content ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>


        <?php if(comments_open() || get_comments_number()){

            $fields = array(
                'author' => '<label class="comment-form-author">Ваше имя'.
                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Ваше имя" required/></label> ',
                'email'  => '<label class="comment-form-email">Ваша почта'.
                    '<input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" size="30" placeholder="Ваша почта" required/></label>',
    'order'  => '<label class="comment-form-text">Ваш заказ'.
                    '<input id="text" name="text" type="number" value="" size="30" placeholder="Ваш заказ" required/></label>',
    'photo'  => '<label class="comment-form-file">Ваше фото'.
                    '<input id="file" name="file" type="file" value="" size="30" placeholder="Ваше фото" required accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)"/></label>
<img id="output"/>',
     

            );
            $c_args = array(
                'fields' => $fields,
                'comment_field' => '<label class="comment-form-comment">Ваш отзыв<textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" placeholder="Ваш отзыв" required></textarea></label>',
                'title_reply'=>'',
                'logged_in_as'=>'',
                'comment_notes_before'=>''

            );

            function sort_comment_fields( $fields ){
                $new_fields = array();
                $my_comment = array('author','email','order','file','comment'); // порядок полей

                foreach( $my_comment as $key ){
                    $new_fields[ $key ] = $fields[ $key ];
                    unset( $fields[ $key ] );
                }

                if( $fields )
                    foreach( $fields as $key => $val )
                        $new_fields[ $key ] = $val;
                return $new_fields;
            }
            add_filter('comment_form_fields', 'sort_comment_fields' );

            /*echo '<div id="leave_testimonial" class="popup_form">
        <div class="title_line">
            Оставить отзыв о квесте
            <span>Форт Боярд</span>
        </div>
        <div class="inputs_wrap">';*/
            comment_form($c_args);
            /*echo '</div></div>';*/
   


        } ?>
  <hr>
        <div class="btn_holder">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Оставить отзыв</a>
        </div>
  <script>
  jQuery(".comment-respond").hide();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".btn_holder").click(function(){
    jQuery(".comment-respond").toggle('slow');
     });
  });
  </script>
  <script>
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
        <!--<div class="pagination">
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="#"><1></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Показать все</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>-->
    </section>
<div class="comment">
        
        <?php if( get_field('upload_image', $comment) ): ?>
            
            <img src="<?php the_field('image', $comment); ?>" />
            
        <?php endif; ?>
    
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: "Как сделать вывод полей в шаблоне комментариев" - каких полей? Вы же сделали "форму комментирования со своими полями".

Comment: А за  `<?= ` руки отрывать нужно. По самое горло